# Как в php запустить математические операции из строки?

Tags: php, математика, str-replace

Всем привет.

Есть такой код:

```
$formula = '{var1} / {var2}'; // можно сложить, умножить, делить и т.д.
$var1 = 100; // тип может быть float
$var2 = 2; // тип может быть float
$phrase = array("{var1}", "{var2}");
$healthy = array((float)$var1, (float)$var2);
$result = str_replace($phrase, $healthy, $formula);
```

Значение $result получаю в виде строки 100 / 2;

Как получить результат после математической операции?

Answer (score 0):

> *Как в php запустить математические операции из строки?*

Используйте [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php), но только для учебных целей:

```
$formula = '{var1} / {var2}'; // можно сложить, умножить, делить и т.д.
$var1 = 100; // тип может быть float
$var2 = 2; // тип может быть float
$phrase = array("{var1}", "{var2}");
$healthy = array((float)$var1, (float)$var2);
$result = str_replace($phrase, $healthy, $formula);

eval("echo $result;");
```

Comment: Работает, но почему "только для учебных целей:", объясните новичку